# Create map from PNG like Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, maps, gis, openlayers

We need to create a map of the small town from raster file. Our client deny usage of known API such as Google Maps, OSM, etc. There is little time before the deadline. What is the quickest way to create a small web map from the picture? Some kind of JavaScript framework?
Requires: drag, zoom and markers.
It is very desirable to do this without a big fat server such as MapServer or GeoServer, because we dont have a much time to redraw map in this format.

Comment: Would this suffice? http://brainmaps.org/index.php?p=brain-maps-api No markers though as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely easiest way is to create an OpenLayers map with `Image` layer. [Here is an example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/image-layer.html) of how it works.

Consider though that whole image is being loaded to the client before OpenLayers can manipulate it. So it's probably not the best option if it's a huge image.

Other option would be to create a tile pyramide with [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.org/) which you can then simply host on your webserver(no need for MapServer or GeoServer) and then use TileCache layer in OpenLayers to display tiles on map. MapTiler creates OpenLayers example with all necessary settings when you tile image with it.